# How can I enhance fudge's "fudginess" and flavour?

Tags: chocolate

My fudge recipe uses peanut butter, brown and white sugar, corn syrup, cream, and chocolate.

How can I can add a bit more "pizazz" to my fudge, taking the flavour from grandma's favourite fudge recipe and making it into a complicated, rich, exotic and exquisite taste?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to think about:

- Sprinkling kosher, sea, or another interesting salt on it for a flavor contrast
- Using some small amount of pepper a la the trendy pepper chocolate bars out there, or perhaps some paprika for smokiness
- Adding orange or lemon zest
- Pairing with an unsweetened or very lightly sweetened raspberry syrup (at least in my experience fudge recipes don't need more sugar)
- Bacon (inside or on top)

Comment: I like the lemon zest idea, what do you think about lime zest + salt, and perhaps freshly made habanero paste?

Comment: @dassouki - I like that idea, mostly because you can start with just lime zest, see if it is enough, add a bit of salt, see if it is enough, then add the paste.  Along the way you'll get ideas upon ideas.  Layering sounds really good.  Plus the flavor combo sounds pretty classic.

Comment: By pepper do you mean red pepper? I have seen the cayenne chocolate and love it, but are you referring to black pepper?

Comment: @mfg - red or perhaps other (habanero has a great fruity flavor and all the fat in that recipe would disseminate the heat), but I wasn't thinking of peppercorns of any sort, no.

Comment: i love all justkt's ideas (well, except the bacon one... i just don't get the bacon fascination, to be honest...) and i'll add one more to the list that i don't see: some instant coffee/espresso. it doesn't take much, just a half teaspoon or so, say, but it really adds depth.

Comment: @franko: Bacon has a very diverse flavour profile including a ton of umami which makes it pair well with many other foods.  If there's any particular fascination with it today, it's probably a result of the slow collective realization that fat isn't inherently bad for you.  I don't know if I'd pair it with fudge either, but I'm sure somebody would eat it...

Comment: @justkt whew, i was trying to wrap my head around a smoked, peppercorn bacon fudge in white chocolate... amazing how repulsion and attraction are so similar

Answer (score 3):

Salt is a must in any chocolate recipe IMO--and not added as an extra texture or flavor at the end. I find that using a little salt in the recipe really bumps up the chocolate flavor in most things.

Answer (score 2):

Cinnamon will compliment the chocolate and add a warmth and richness to fudge. The darker the chocolate, the better. Instant espresso powder is another great addition.

Comment: cinnamon sounds good what do yo think about adding cloves or cardamom

Comment: I think cardamom would be great, cloves I would be careful as a little goes a long way...not sure how they would work with peanut butter though - in your recipe is this for taste or consistency? You may be able to use sweetened condensed milk instead. It gives it a "fudgey" consistency without being overly sweet if used in place of sugar.

Comment: I am also a huge fan of adding a pinch of cayenne pepper when working with flavors like chocolate, coffee, and cinnamon. It adds just a bit of heat (similar to Mexican chocolate).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're using for chocolate, but there is certainly an opportunity there to try some variations.